# The below VBA code is working on my home laptop (Excel 2016) but not on my work one (Excel 2010), Error '438'

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()

   Dim Fname As String
   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
   Dim DestWbk As Workbook

   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

   SrcWbk.Sheets("Projects Register").Range("A1:V500").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("ProjectsDelivery").Range("A2,V500")

   SrcWbk.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are  you sure it's that code? There's nothing in there that would differ between versions.

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: The only thing that looks odd to me is the very last thing before closing it. `.Range("A2,V500")` there is a comma there. Maybe try ":" instead. That is unless you mean to copy it to 2 places. If so, then just split it into 2 instances of pasting it. Its slower but for this tiny macro maybe not important. I dunno the old syntax for copying to 2 places off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: I get error on the 3rd line from bottom, I'm getting an error which says it doesn't work on multiple selections?

Comment: Yeah so its the ",". Do you need to copy it to 2 places? Or just have your stuff in the same range on another sheet? if so, change the destination to: `DestWbk.Sheets("ProjectsDelivery").Range("A1:V500")`

Comment: the same error is returned when changed? no I only need to copy into 1 sheet

Comment: Please try `SrcWbk.Sheets("Projects Register").Range("A1:V500").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("ProjectsDelivery").Range("A2")` and confirm that this is the line that gives the problem.

Comment: That now works, Thankyou!

Comment: That's not an error **438** though??